# How to log the response code of all web requests in .NET Core

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my .NET Core 2.2 Web Api project, I want to log any returned status code.

I created a standard Web Api project and modified a method to do exactly this.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"RESPONSE STATUSCODE  + {context.Response.StatusCode}");
        await next.Invoke();
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

I seems to work for regular calls. For example,

`curl --silent -i http://localhost:5000/api/values | grep HTTP`

returns

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK

And the logging is:

> RESPONSE STATUSCODE  + 200

However, when I do this request

`curl --silent -i http://localhost:5000/nonsense | grep HTTP`

I get this returned:

> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

And the logging is the same.....

> RESPONSE STATUSCODE  + 200

I just want to log my returned status code. That's all. How to do this? It seems to work fine if a 200 is returned but not in other situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because your logging is placed incorrectly in the request pipeline, have a read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2). When you log, the response is still a default one having 200 status code, the pipeline is not finished processing yet.

You'll need to move your logging to be `the last` in the pipeline for handling the response, and move the call after `next.Invoke()` like in this sample:

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {

            await next.Invoke();
            Console.WriteLine($"RESPONSE STATUSCODE  + {context.Response.StatusCode}");
        });
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseMvc();


    }
```